# Can I send an array (not a collection) to a Laravel API Resource to transform the data?

Tags: laravel, api, resources

In the official examples a model (collection) is sent to resources.

If I want to transform an array format to another array format, would it be a good way to use the resource? I just want to keep the best practices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to pass an array to the Resource.